# How to convert pandas dataframe column value into an iterable collection?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirement to convert the comma separated string values of a pandas dataframe column into an iterable collection that can be either a list or an array, so we can iterate and do operation on the obtained set of values.

You can understand it with below given sample data:

```
__________________________
index | column1
__________________________
0     | val1, val2, val3
__________________________
1     | val3, val4
__________________________
2     | val5, val6, val7
__________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand what you want: you use split to create list in each row, so you can iterate each row and each list of column1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['val1, val2, val3', 'val4, val5, val6', 'val7, val8']}) 
print(df)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.column1.split(','),axis=1)    
print(df)
```

output:

```
            column1
0  val1, val2, val3
1  val4, val5, val6
2        val7, val8
```

final result.

```
0    [val1,  val2,  val3]
1    [val4,  val5,  val6]
2           [val7,  val8]
```